# Facebook pulling content from the wrong URL

Tags: facebook, mobile

I'm using [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to detect if user is accessing our website from a mobile, tablet or desktop, and our conditional is,

```
if($detectmob == 'mobile' || $detectmob == 'tablet'){
      header("Location: http://m.foo.com".$requestedUrl);
}
```

That works flawlessly, if user enter our site with a mobile it gets redirected to a mobile version, etc...
The problem we have is that if we copy the desktop URL `http://foo.com/article/nice-article.html` and paste it into facebook to share it with our community the information that Facebook pulls is from the mobile version `http://m.foo.com/article/nice-article.html` even if we use any other tool to share on Facebook, like ShareIt or ShareThis, it stil pulls the information from the mobile version, why is that? does it has to do with Bots?... we haven't made any changes for that subject... How can we solve this?

Comment: Use the debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: the real url would be better for testing. i assume, you are using the same og:url?

Comment: @WizKid I did and get's a canonical URL but also a redirect to that canonical url which is the mobile version and just today I was thinking to work on the canonical URL because the desktop url is a bit different from the mobile version the information is the same...

Comment: @luschn yes, mobile and desktop have their own social tags and the url's match at to what is on the address bar

Comment: @WizKid that got me thinking, to build your canonical url you have to declare them on your script but that hasn't been done, the other way to declare canonicals is via .htaccess, and there was the %$^%$&^%^ problem! another DEV that didn't show up today was using the mod_header.c and that my friend, was the cause for this problem!, I'm gonna kill that guy...